# loop inside "THIS" selector with xpath, scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I´m using scrapy to crawl some information, but im stunned with the handle of the data. At `for` loop, first step is locate a "root" xpath called `selectors`, then is looped. My mind says, if is the first selector, is the first selector of `ul`, then I can crawl all the data of the first selector! Instead, scrapy returns an array of all elements. I´m using selector varible as 'THIS'

```
import Scrapy

class SecccionAmarillaSpider( scrapy.spider ):
 name="seccion_amarilla"
 start_urls = ['https://www.seccionamarilla.com.mx/resultados/hospitales/1']
 data = {}

  def parse( self, result ):
    selectors = result.xpath('//ul[@class="list"]/li')
    for selector in selectors:
     name = selector.xpath('//span[itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
     phone = selector.xpath('//span[itemprop="telephone"]/text()').extract()
     #These data is stored in MySQL
```

[image: Example]
For example, on the first loop I expect

```
name = 'Z'
phone = '( 81)8333 4662'
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES('"+name+"','"+phone+"')"
```

Instead, I recived in the first loop

```
name = ['Z','Z-GAS']
phone = ['( 81)8333 4662', '(33)3668 3800']
```

All the loops the same data, is not respecting current selector?

**WHY?**

I can´t make a relation between arrays because sometimes the selector has not name and/or phone and Scrapy doesnt return None or null or empty.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Read about [supported-xpath-syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) the meaning of `//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

1. In XPath, you should refer to attributes with the `@` prefix: `//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()`
2. You should use relative XPath in your for loop: `.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()`
3. You should use the `.extract_first()` method instead of `.extract()` (which returns a list)

So, your code should be something along these lines:

```
for selector in selectors:
    name = selector.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
    phone = selector.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="telephone"]/text()').extract_first()
    ...
```